# How to do a httprequest with some dynamic url clientside, but do not redirect to this url?

Tags: client-object-model, custom-actions

I created a custom action with some javascript inside of it. I would like to genereate dynamic some url. Then I would like to do a httprequest to this url. BUT I do not want to redirect to this url, so I need to stay on the current page.

```
    function RequestUrl()
    {
       var dynamicUrl = 'http://myCompany.com/sv/sv_000124/_layouts/15/SendToOfficialFile.aspx?ID=rm0001
    &Index=beb7b694-9aef-40b2-8910-a6637e138032&SourceUrl=%2Fsv%2Fsv%5F000124%2FGedeelde%20documenten%2FScrum%2DGuide%2DNL%2Epdf';

      // Do a httprequest clientside of the url above ??

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with an ajax httprequest:

```
function ArchiveDocuments() {
    var dynamicUrl = 'http://myCompany.com/sv/sv_000124/_layouts/15/SendToOfficialFile.aspx';

    $.ajax(
                {
                    url: dynamicUrl,
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8",
                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                    },
                    error: function (err) {

                    }
                });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any more code I presume you execute this on a SharePoint page and the click event bubbles up the DOM and is caught by (the) SharePoint Form or anothe click event on the page..

So you need to cancel the events.

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

or

```
event.preventDefault();
```

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963669/whats-the-difference-between-event-stoppropagation-and-event-preventdefault